# Collect all Rake routes which have method 'GET'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have an array of rake routes, and I am trying to extract all of the routes which have route.conditions[:request_method] as GET.

Problems:

```
:request_method is a regex (:request_method=>/^GET$/)

> routes.select { |route| route.conditions[:request_method] == /GET/ }  
> []
```

I figured my select was correct. This works, and outputs all route methods:

```
> routes.each { |route| print route.conditions[:request_method] }
> {:request_method=>/^GET$/}{:request_method=>/^GET$/}{:request_method=>/^PUT$/}{:request_method=>/^GET$/}{:request_method=>/^PUT$/}{:request_method=>/^POST$/}{:request_method=>/^GET$/}{:request_method=>/^GET$/}
```

Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. routes.each was returning the Journey object, so I first created my own custom hash:

```
routes = Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a
routes = routes.collect { |route| {name: route.name, method: route.verb} }
routes = routes.select { |route| route[:method] == /^GET$/ }
```

I'm sure this can be more elegantly reworked so I'm open to changes. It works, that's the most important part.